# Symfony2 redirect to https route fails (uses wrong port)

Tags: symfony

I set up symfony so that login/register are https routes and work fine. The problem arises when on logout the user is redirected to the login page, here symfony2 redirects to `https://domain.com:80/login` which is using the wrong port and fails. The only way I found to fix this is to place absolute urls in configuration like this

```
logout: 
            path:   /logout
            target: https://www.domain.com/login
```

but i'm sure there must be a better way to fix this.

Any idea what needs to be done?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened on any redirect, eg from a url without dash to a url with dash, it would redirect to the correct protocol (https) but to the wrong port (80). AFAIK it seems Symfony routing relies on the SERVER_PORT global instead of what's specified in the request URI. So my only fix was to set it before symfony2 starts in app.php, `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;`
 hack but it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using nginx than this mite fix the problem:
http://blog.servergrove.com/2011/04/04/symfony2-quick-tip-generateurl-with-https-on-nginx/

Missing fastcgi param:

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using nginx + php-fpm and adding HTTPS param solved the issue!

Comment: I encountered a similar problem, because I'd put both HTTP and SSL into the same nginx server config entry, and had "fastcgi_param HTTPS on" in there. So accessing '/protected' redirected to https://server:80/login ... Splitting out into two separate nginx server configs (two separate files in sites-available) worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using varnish, add this in app.php :

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] = 443;
```