# PHP; Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset

Tags: php, apache, symfony, openshift

I have symfony 2 application which works fine on local computer. I uploaded it to 
redhat's openshift cloud server. When I access the following page

```
https://jba-hj.rhcloud.com/web/app.php
```

it should redirect to

```
https://jba-hj.rhcloud.com/web/app.php/login
```

page, but server adds port number 80 to the url, i.e., it becomes:

```
https://jba-hj.rhcloud.com:80/web/app.php/login
```

and throws the following error:

```
 Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

If I delete port number, and reload the page, then login page displays correctly.
The same error happens after login. (For the time being, you can try this by actually browsing to the urls above).

I checked $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] variable on openshift server, and it returns 80; i.e,
openshift's Apache server port number is 80.

How to fix the problem?

Comment: See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629255/symfony2-redirect-to-https-route-fails-uses-wrong-port

Answer (score 0):

In app.php and app_dev.php, I added

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
```

at the beginning, just after require_once statement.

See:
[Symfony2 redirect to https route fails (uses wrong port)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629255/symfony2-redirect-to-https-route-fails-uses-wrong-port)